# React Query data

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fetch, react-query

Im using React Query to fetch data and the function completes just fine.

Im console.log ing the data variable from the React Query and it prints an array of objects just like I want it to,
and further than that it manages the states well between `loading, success, error`.

the problem is I cannot do anything with the array. im trying to use `map()` method to render the data, inside the `return` but i get an error "Cannot read properties of undefined".
I also tried to assign the data to a different variable before returning any value and then iterating over that variable but again the same error.

can someone help me iterate over that data array?

fetch function:

```
export async function fetchEntireGarden() {
   console.log('fetching garden')
   const response = await fetch(`${BASIC_URL}/getEntireGarden`)
   const entireGardenArray = await response.json()
   return entireGardenArray
```

}

relevant component, the 'console.log(data)' prints just fine:

```
const { isError, status, isSuccess, isLoading, data, error } = useQuery(
    ['garden'],
    fetchEntireGarden,
)
let originalPlantsHolder: Plant[] = []

if (status === 'loading') { return <Spinner /> }
if (status === 'error') { return 'Could Not Complete your request'}
console.log(data)

    originalPlantsHolder = data
if (status === 'success') {
    return (
        <>
            <div className="page-container">
                <div id="my-garden-content">
                    <div id="my-garden-options">
                        <div id="buttons">
                        <GreenButton text="Add a Plant" onClick={() => setAddPlantModal(true)}/>
                        <RedButton text="Remove Plants" onClick={() => setRemoveButtons(!removeButtons)}/>
                        {removeButtons && <>
                            <RedButton text="Select All" onClick={selectAll}/>
                            <RedButton text="Remove Permanently" onClick={removePlantsPermanently}/>
                                        </>
                        }
                        </div>
                        <div id="search-bar-and-count">
                            <div id="search-bar-left"><img src={searchLogo}/></div>
                            <input id="search-bar" type="text" ref={searchBarInputRef} onChange={handleSearch} placeholder="Search" />
                            <div id="plants-counter">You Have {plants.length} Plants</div>
                        </div>    
                    </div>
                    
                    <div id="plants-container">
            
                        {originalPlantsHolder.map((plant: Plant) =>
                        <Link to={`/PlantTimeline/${plant.id}`} key={plant.id}>
                            <div className="plant-card" onClick={() => updateCurrentPlant(plant)}>
                                {removeButtons && <input
                                                    checked={plant.checked}
                                                    className="toggle"
                                                    type="checkbox"
                                                    onChange={() => checkBoxPlant(plant.id)}/>
                                }
                                <img width="100" src={`data:image/png;base64,${bufferToImage(plant.imageBufferArray)}`} alt={plant.name}/>
                                <h5> {capitalize(plant.name)} </h5>
                            </div>
                        </Link>
                        )}
                    </div>
                </div>
    
                
            </div>
            {addPlantModal && <Modal open={addPlantModal} onClose={() => setAddPlantModal(false)} content={<AddPlantForm plants={plants} setPlants={setPlants} setModal={setAddPlantModal}/>}></Modal>}
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: what is the output of this line before you get an error? `console.log(data)`

Comment: copied from browser console: 

`(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]`
`0 : {img: {…}, _id: '640cab67d5491aadfae80780', plantName: 'alocasia dragon ', irrigations: Array(0), dateAdded: '03/11/2023', …}`
`1: {img: {…}, _id: '640cd1014e35d6ac2f434b01', plantName: 'monstera deliciosa', irrigations: Array(0), dateAdded: '03/11/2023', …}`
`2: img: {…}, _id: '640cdc6c8ecbdb98d6e031c8', plantName: 'alocasia green velvet', irrigations: Array(0), dateAdded: '03/11/2023', …}`
`length: 3`
`[[Prototype]]: Array(0)`

Answer (score 0):

In your larger JSX block you have

```
<div id="plants-counter">You Have {plants.length} Plants</div>
```

but `plants` isn't defined anywhere in your code. It probably needs to be

```
<div id="plants-counter">You Have {originalPlantsHolder.length} Plants</div>
```

You're also using `plants` in the `Modal` code further down which could be causing a problem.